# Extracting a JSON out of a string using JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have Json data as follows:

```
{
   "template" : [
      "{
         "Id": "abc"
      }"
   ]
}
```

I am using **JSONPath** to extract data from the Json above. I would like to extract the "Id" data from the Json using JsonPath.

The problem I see is, the data is being treated as a string and not as a Json as shown below.

```
"{
   "Id": "abc"
}"
```

If there were no *double-quotes* I could have used JsonPath as follows:

```
$.template[0].Id
```

But due to the double-quotes, I am unable to access the "Id" data. I suspect there is a way to access this data using **JsonPath-Expression** but I am pretty much a novice here and no amount of research helped me out with a resolution.

How do I treat it as a Json and not as a string using JsonPath? Kindly help me out here.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.  The interior quotes (i.e. around `Id` and `abc`) should be escaped.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this and that is precisely the issue here. I got to deal with those quotes and preferably using JsonPath.

Comment: Can you edit your question to better explain what you're trying to do?  JSON Path is only going to work on valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

JSON Path isn't going to be able to parse JSON that's encoded within a string. You need to perform three operations:

1. Get the string (use JSON Path or something else)
2. Parse the string as JSON.
3. Get the data you're looking for on that (JSON Path or something else)